# What is the difference between these two uses of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Class "**a**" contains attributes: *service_* of type **boost::asio_ioservice** and *sock_*, a **unique_ptr** **of type** **boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket**.

The following constructor code exists with sock_ properly pointing at a new socket object.

```
a::a() : service_(), sock_(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(service_))
{
}
```

The following constructor code does not. The debugger lists sock_ as "empty".

```
a::a() : service_(), sock_(nullptr)
{
     sock_(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(service_));
}
```

Why?

Comment: `sock`is not `sock_`

Comment: Don't you mean `sock_(new ..)`? With the underscore? And that's not how you *assign to* a variable. There's a difference between *initialization* (what you do in the first snippet of code) and *assignment*.

Comment: There's an unbalanced paren in the second code sample. Please post real code.

Comment: `sock_(nullptr)` a std::unique_ptr doesn't need a initialisation with null.

Comment: @manni66 the real code is now there

Comment: I am pretty shure that that _real code_ will not compile.

Comment: @manni66 It will and will later cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a statement:

> `sock_(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(service_));`

is simply not valid c++. Did you think of

```
sock_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(service_));
```

instead?

Or

```
sock_ = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(service_);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling something was fundamentally wrong.